# GetSystemTime and taskbarTime not matched

Tags: get, set, taskbar, systemtime

I want to change SystemTime in C#. I used `SetSystemTime()` and changed the System Date and Time successfully, but after changing it ,in task bar, only date is changed and task bar time doesn't change at all.

And when I call GetSysemTime I can see date and time changes.
how can i Read Taskbar Time programmatically?or In other words does taskbar time refer to systemTime?
Help Please

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the two times will be due to time zone settings.

Check HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation and adjust your reading accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Taskbar Time Alwayse show this:
GetSystemTime +UTC (of Time Zone)

and when we set special Time , GetSystemTime Exactly show The Time We set, but taskbarTime Add Utc of timeZone to that!
Thank You